# How to sum monthly data in Excel into quarterly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

As the title says, I would like to convert monthly Excel data into quarterly by summing the 3 previous cells (i.e merge January, February and March 2003 data into Q1 2003)

Much thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us some more insight in how your data looks? Use [Markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) formatting for example. Doesn't have to be full data, but at least representative. And perhaps add in a desired outcome table.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, here are few examples:

• If there are only month names:

[image]

---

```
=SUM(("Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1:A12&0)/3,)=D1)*(B1:B12))
```

---

• If the dates are true dates then:

Sample data used for the following formulas:

| DATES | VALUES |
| --- | --- |
| January 31, 2003 | 114 |
| February 1, 2003 | 163 |
| March 1, 2003 | 178 |
| April 1, 2003 | 176 |
| May 1, 2003 | 125 |
| June 1, 2003 | 191 |
| July 1, 2003 | 118 |
| August 1, 2003 | 104 |
| September 1, 2003 | 148 |
| October 1, 2003 | 109 |
| November 1, 2003 | 162 |
| December 1, 2003 | 123 |

---

```
=SUM(("Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1:A12&0)/3,)&" "&YEAR(A1:A12)=D1)*(B1:B12))
```

---

Or if applicable using `GROUPBY()` to get all the quarters :

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY("Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1:A12&0)/3,)&" "&YEAR(A1:A12),B1:B12,SUM,,0)
```

---

If one don't have access to `GROUPBY()` then using `BYROW()` or `MMULT()`

```
=LET(
     _Quarters, "Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1:A12&0)/3,),
     _Years, YEAR(A1:A12),
     _Unique, UNIQUE(_Quarters&" "&_Years),
     _Sum, MMULT(N(_Unique=TOROW(_Quarters&" "&_Years)),B1:B12),
     SORT(HSTACK(_Unique, _Sum)))
```

---

```
=LET(
     _Quarters, "Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1:A12&0)/3,),
     _Years, YEAR(A1:A12),
     _Unique, UNIQUE(_Quarters&" "&_Years),
     _Sum, BYROW(_Unique,LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=_Quarters&" "&_Years)*B1:B12))),
     SORT(HSTACK(_Unique, _Sum)))
```

---

**Note:** Since there is no sample mock up data, hence you may need to change the range and ranges as per your suit.

---

Comment: My day column is in the following format: 2003-01-31

Comment: @Stefan that should not be problem you can try any one of the following. If those are `True` Excel Dates, which means when you select the cell and hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`~` it will convert to a number, for example `2003-01-31` will be `37652` if it does, there is no issue if it doesn't then those dates are formatted as text

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a basic example of your data when asking the question. As is, your question is quite nebulous and it is unclear what form your sheet is in.

As a very basic example, assuming you have a single column of data with each cell representing a single month in column A, you can easily sum each set of 3 cells in column B. In B3, you can use the formula

`=SUM(A1:A3)`

and then copy it to every B cell that is divisible by 3 (6, 9, 12, 15, etc.)

If you want something you can simply copy throughout the column, you could use

`=IF(MOD(ROW(B3), 3) = 0, SUM(A1:A3), "")`

as it will skip all non 3 divisible rows.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are formatted as dates you could create a pivot table that handles the dates allowing you to sum by flexible periods (year, quarter, period). Just highlight your data and select Insert pivot table and drag the date into the appropriate fields. Then right click and select "group" and you'll see all the date options

You can also create a table where you do a lookup on the first day of each month with a non-exact match, and label the rows with the respective quarters then do a sumifs from those quarters.